# Outputting variable value into innerHTML with JQuery and then storing it in PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

Essentially, I'm attempting to capture the value of a HTML drop down menu and call a php function (i.e., print_wp_cart_button_for_product) with the user selected row.  I have created a JQuery function which is called onchange, but have encountered several problems.  By using alerts, I'm sure that the function is called and that the value is stored in currentrow.  Additionally, by using the firefox web console, I know that order.php is called with the appropriate parameters.  Originally I was using ajax success method, but the function was not being called, so I switched it to the complete method, which at least solved the fist problem.  The second issue I'm dealing with involves storing the variable currentrow in the innerHTML of test.  When I changed $('#test').html(currentrow) to $('#test').html("Complete") the string was outputted to the screen, as I would expect, but I've been unable to do so dynamically with the value of the currentrow.  The last problem I've found involves saving the value of the test div tag into a php variable.  I've attempted to use $_GET to capture the value and subsequently call my php function, but have had no luck.

```
  <div id="test">
  </div>

  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function productchange() 
  {
      var currentrow = $('#productcategory1').val();
      //alert(currentrow);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themeX/order.php",
        data: {'rownum': currentrow},
        complete: function(currentrow){
            //alert('COMPLETE');
            $('#test').html(currentrow);
            //$('#test').html("Complete");
            }});      
      return false;
  }
  </script>

 <?php $rownum = $_GET['test']; ?>
 <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($products[$rownum]["Product"], $products[$rownum]["Price"]); ?>
```

Order.php

```
<?php
$rownum= $_GET['rownum'];
echo "Row number = $rownum";
?>
```

Comment: Try removing currentrow from the complete function. It should still be available inside of the complete function without passing it as a parameter. My thought is that you are referencing the local variable currentrow instead of the one you defined at the top of the function.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks danL, that solved my second problem.  Now I need to save the value of currentrow, which is stored both in the url of order.php as well as in the innerHTML of the test div tag, into a php variable in order to call print_wp_cart_button_for_product.  My current strategy of using $_GET hasn't been successful.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try storing the value in a hidden form field and posting it to the PHP page with ajax. If you need a code snippet let me know and I can write one up for you.

Comment: That would be fantastic!  I've been struggling with these issues for the last few days. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `<div id="test"></div>` should really be `<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test"/>` within a `<form>`

Using a form element of some kind is the only way you can natively pass a value back to the server on submit.

In any case, the inline PHP code after your HTML will only work after submit of a form.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I do not want to submit a form and reload the entire page.  The value of the drop down menu corresponds to a row in a product array, which is selected by the user. Subsequently, the row is used within the add to cart button [i.e.,<?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($products[$rownum]["Product"], $products[$rownum]["Price"]); ] I understand that the PHP occurs on the server side, so how would I go about calling the php function with the user selected row without reloading the page?

Comment: you would need to use an AJAX responder of somekind: another PHP script that only responds to AJAX requests and does the data processing, then returns a response that your javascript/jquery will handle.  check the internet for examples of how to do this, starting with the jquery docs on the `.post()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code that will submit a hidden form field to the PHP page allowing you to store the value in a PHP variable. First, do something like this on the main page which has your javascript.

```
<form method="post" action="storevar.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="jsvar" id="jsvar" value="" />
</form>
```

Then, after you have calculated the value that variable should be in javascript, update the value of this hidden form field with Javascript/JQuery, like this:

```
function productchange() {
  var currentrow = $('#productcategory1').val();
  $("#jsvar").val(currentrow);

   $.post('storevar.php', {jsvar: currentrow}, function(data) {
             // do any additional coding with the result if need be  
         }

    });  

  return false;
}
```

Then you could do something like this in storevar.php. Notice I'm storing it in a session so that it can be retrieved in other pages as well if you need to.

```
session_start();
$currentrow = $_POST['jsvar'];
$_SESSION['currentrow'] = $currentrow;
```

I hope that helps you. If you need any additional help, or if I've misunderstood something, please let me know and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: This definitely appears to be a step in the right direction.  I haven't worked with session variables, but they should come in handy as I continue to integrate my shopping cart.  I'm still having an issue with my add to cart button though.  On the main page I have altered my function call to: <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($products[$_SESSION['currentrow']]["Product"], $products[$_SESSION['currentrow']]["Price"]); ?>.  I changed the methods from Get from Post and added a few echo lines to storevar.php to make sure that the current row variable and the

Comment: $Session['currentrow'] was capturing the value of jsvar.  Unfortunately the add to cart button still is not working in the manner i need.  Given that the PHP is occurring on the server side, is it possible that I have to refresh the echo of the button itself? Once the page is loaded for the user, are the values of the php variables set?  Thus meaning that the function is being called with an uninitialized variable $_SESSION['currentrow']?

Comment: Make sure you are calling session_start() on every page that needs to access that PHP variable. Additionally, you should probably update the current page's content via a javascript/jquery call because although the PHP variable is technically set even on the current page, it won't be available until the page is refreshed or updated with JS/Jquery, since PHP is a sever-side language. On a side note, you can always check to see if a variable is set in PHP with isset() so that you don't get errors inside your function. I hope that answers your question. If you're still having trouble, let me know.

Comment: Using the isset() function I was able to confirm my suspicion that the $_SESSION['currentrow'] variable is not initialized thus the cause of my problems.  Ideally I would like to refresh only the add-to-cart button, I added div tags around the echo wp_cart_button_for_product function call and was attempting to use the JQuery load function to update the $_Session variables within the php function call, but didn't have any luck.  Is there another way to go about doing this?  I'm not entirely sure what to include within the load URL file as I only want it to update the variable values.